# How to re-render a custom hook after initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have custom hook named `useIsUserSubscribed` that checks to see a specific user is subscribed. It returns true if the user is subscribed and false if the user is not subscribed...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { checkSubscription } from "../services";

// this hook checks if the current user is subscribed to a particular user(publisherId)
function useIsUserSubscribed(publisherId) {
  const [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed] = useState(null);
  const currentUserId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user?.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUserId || !publisherId) return;

    async function fetchCheckSubscriptionData() {
      try {
        const res = await checkSubscription(publisherId);
        setUserIsSubscribed(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setUserIsSubscribed(false);
      }
    }

    fetchCheckSubscriptionData();
  }, [publisherId, currentUserId]);

  return userIsSubscribed;
}

export default useIsUserSubscribed;
```

...I have a button using this hook that renders text conditionally based on the boolean returned from `useIsUserSubscribed`...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { add, remove } from "../../services";
import useIsUserSubscribed from "../../hooks/useIsUserSubscribed";

const SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn = ({profilePageUserId}) => {

  const userIsSubscribed = useIsUserSubscribed(profilePageUserId);
  
  const onClick = async () => {
    if (userIsSubscribed) {
       // this is an API Call to the backend
      await removeSubscription(profilePageUserId);

    } else {
      // this is an API Call to the backend
      await addSubscription(profilePageUserId);
    }
    // HOW CAN I RERENDER THE HOOK HERE!!!!?
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" className="sub-edit-unsub-btn bsc-button" onClick={onClick}>
          {userIsSubscribed ? 'Subscribed' : 'Unsubscribed'}
    </button>
  );
}
```

After `onClick` I would like to rerender my the `useIsUserSubscribed` hook So that my button text toggles. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not use useEffect in your hook for that purpose try this :

hook :

```
function useIsUserSubscribed() {
  const currentUserId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user?.id);


  const checkUser = useCallback(async (publisherId, setUserIsSubscribed) => {
    if (!currentUserId || !publisherId) return;
      try {
        const res = await checkSubscription(publisherId);
        setUserIsSubscribed(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setUserIsSubscribed(false);
      }
    
  }, [currentUserId]);

  return {checkUser};
}

export default useIsUserSubscribed;
```

component :

```
const SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn = ({profilePageUserId}) => {
    const [userIsSubscribed,setUserIsSubscribed]=useState(false);
    const { checkUser } = useIsUserSubscribed();

     useEffect(()=>{
        checkUser(profilePageUserId,setUserIsSubscribed)
     },[checkUser,profilePageUserId]);
  
  const onClick = async () => {
    if (userIsSubscribed) {
       // this is an API Call to the backend
      await removeSubscription(profilePageUserId);

    } else {
      // this is an API Call to the backend
      await addSubscription(profilePageUserId);
    }
    // HOW CAN I RERENDER THE HOOK HERE!!!!?
    checkUser(profilePageUserId,setUserIsSubscribed)
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" className="sub-edit-unsub-btn bsc-button" onClick={onClick}>
          {userIsSubscribed ? 'Subscribed' : 'Unsubscribed'}
    </button>
  );
}
```

you can also add some loading state in your hook and return them too so you can check if process is already done or not

Comment: I intend to reused this logic in other parts if the application. What is a better way to make this reusable if the hook is not the best approach?

Comment: @SimoneAnthony nothing wrong with hooks and you can use it but I also noticed you use redux so you can use redux-thunk actions too

Answer (score 2):

Add a dependece on useIsUserSubscribed's useEffect.

hook :

```
function useIsUserSubscribed(publisherId) {
    const [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed] = useState(null);
    const currentUserId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user?.id);
    // add refresh dependece
    const refresh = useSelector((state) => state.auth.refresh);

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
    }, [publisherId, currentUserId, refresh]);
    ...
}
```

component :

```
const onClick = async () => {
    ...
    // HOW CAN I RERENDER THE HOOK HERE!!!!?
    // when click, you can dispatch a refresh flag.
    dispatch(refreshSubState([]))
}
```

Expose forceUpdate metheod.

hook :

```
function useIsUserSubscribed(publisherId) {
    const [update, setUpdate] = useState({});
    const forceUpdate = () => {
        setUpdate({});
    }  

    return {userIsSubscribed, forceUpdate};
}
```

component :

```
const {userIsSubscribed, forceUpdate} = useIsUserSubscribed(profilePageUserId);

const onClick = async () => {
    ...
    forceUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution by user @bitspook

`SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn` has a dependency on `useIsUserSubscribed`, but `useIsUserSubscribed` don't depend on anything from `SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn`.
Instead, `useIsUserSubscribed` is keeping a local state. You have a couple of choices here:

1. Move the state regarding whetehr user is subscribed or not one level up, since you are using Redux, perhaps in Redux.
2. Communicate to `useIsUserSubscribed` that you need to change its internal state.

For `1)`

```
  const [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed] = useState(null);
```

move this state to Redux store and use it with useSelector.

For `2)`, return an array of value and callback from the hook, instead of just the value. It will allow you to communicate from component back into the hook.

In `useIsUserSubscribed`,

```js
  return [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed];
```

Then in `onClick`, you can call `setUserIsSubscribed(false)`, changing the hook's internal state, and re-rendering your component.