# How to re-render a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have custom hook named `useIsUserSubscribed` that checks to see a specific user is subscribed. It returns true if the user is subscribed and false if the user is not subscribed...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { checkSubscription } from "../services";

// this hook checks if the current user is subscribed to a particular user(publisherId)
function useIsUserSubscribed(publisherId) {
  const [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed] = useState(null);
  const currentUserId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user?.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUserId || !publisherId) return;

    async function fetchCheckSubscriptionData() {
      try {
        const res = await checkSubscription(publisherId);
        setUserIsSubscribed(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setUserIsSubscribed(false);
      }
    }

    fetchCheckSubscriptionData();
  }, [publisherId, currentUserId]);

  return userIsSubscribed;
}

export default useIsUserSubscribed;
```

...I have a button using this hook that renders text conditionally based on the boolean returned from `useIsUserSubscribed`...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { add, remove } from "../../services";
import useIsUserSubscribed from "../../hooks/useIsUserSubscribed";

const SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn = ({profilePageUserId}) => {

  const userIsSubscribed = useIsUserSubscribed(profilePageUserId);
  
  const onClick = async () => {
    if (userIsSubscribed) {
       // this is an API Call to the backend
      await removeSubscription(profilePageUserId);

    } else {
      // this is an API Call to the backend
      await addSubscription(profilePageUserId);
    }
    // HOW CAN I RERENDER THE HOOK HERE!!!!?
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" className="sub-edit-unsub-btn bsc-button" onClick={onClick}>
          {userIsSubscribed ? 'Subscribed' : 'Unsubscribed'}
    </button>
  );
}
```

After `onClick` I would like to rerender my the `useIsUserSubscribed` hook So that my button text toggles. Can this be done? Should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn` has a dependency on `useIsUserSubscribed`, but `useIsUserSubscribed` don't depend on anything from `SubscribeUnsubscribeBtn`.
Instead, `useIsUserSubscribed` is keeping a local state. You have a couple of choices here:

1. Move the state regarding whetehr user is subscribed or not one level up, since you are using Redux, perhaps in Redux.
2. Communicate to `useIsUserSubscribed` that you need to change its internal state.

For `1)`

```
  const [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed] = useState(null);
```

move this state to Redux store and use it with useSelector.

For `2)`, return an array of value and callback from the hook, instead of just the value. It will allow you to communicate from component back into the hook.

In `useIsUserSubscribed`,

```js
  return [userIsSubscribed, setUserIsSubscribed];
```

Then in `onClick`, you can call `setUserIsSubscribed(false)`, changing the hook's internal state, and re-rendering your component.

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate, Do you mind putting your answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090096/how-to-re-render-a-custom-hook-after-initial-render
It will help alot of people. I will make sure to give you an upvote.

Comment: Looks like you've posted the answer on the other question. So I suppose I'll just leave this here.